# Title case for simple_form labels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, capitalization

The following code gives a label of "Project address":

```
%h2 New Project
= simple_form_for(@project, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}, wrapper: :horizontal_form) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.input :project_address, required: true
  = f.button :submit, "Create"
```

Is there any way of making the label title case ("Project Address") apart from using `f.label`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanted to title case all labels, you can **configure simple form in the initializer**:

```
# config/initializers/simple_form.rb
# How the label text should be generated altogether with the required text.
config.label_text = lambda { |label, required, explicit_label| "#{required} #{explicit_label ? label : label.to_s.titleize}" }
```

This will make all your labels title case unless you specify the label explicitly with the `:label` option.

Comment: For those wondering, `explicit_label` is a boolean, not a string.

Comment: I don't think the `to_s` call is necessary here, `label.titleize` should be sufficient